# C string.h inquiry about int vs char

Tags: c, char, int

I understand the differences between char and int and almost all types. I just don't understand why int c is used? Isn't this a different bit size than C? I just want to understand why they use int instead char for the parameter c. I appreciate the knowledge.

Here are the methods/functions I am talking about?

```
char *strchr(const char *str, int c);
char *strrchr(const char *str, int c);
```

I know there are more.

Comment: Google "c integer promotion", lots of good hits.

Comment: perfect. pretty much what I was working for, just some solid reasoning.

Comment: beside the char promotion to int in C, there is also the char being looked for could be '\n' which, depending on the OS may be 1 or 2 bytes (in windows/DOS it is two bytes, in most other OSs it is one byte.)